# Salesforce: Dynamically grabbing record id's in a Lightning Component

Tags: javascript, salesforce, apex, salesforce-lightning

So, I have built a component where I use apex to send Case data to the front end for display in a Community.

I am using a redirect function in the JS controller to take users to the Case detail page.

I need someway to actually grab the specific case Id when a user clicks on a case on the component.

The data is all currently displayed in regular tables tags.

`<aura:iteration items="{!c.caseDisplayMethod}" >
        <td><span onclick="redirectFunction"> {!case.caseNumber}</span></td>
   </aura:iteration>`

Answer (score 0):

**Component Code**

```
<aura:attribute name="caseIdData" type="String"/>

<aura:iteration items="{!v.casesList}" var="item" indexVar="idx">
    <td>
        <span onclick="{!c.redirectFunction}" data-target="{!item.Id}">{!item.CaseNumber}</span>
    </td>
    <br/>
</aura:iteration>
```

**Controller Code**

```
redirectFunction : function(component, event, helper)
{
    var caseIdData = event.currentTarget.getAttribute("data-target");
    component.set("v.caseIdData",caseIdData);
    console.log(caseIdData)
}
```

You can get the data using index var and data record, then you can store the Id in aura:attribute and use it for you further execution.